# Do you expect that future CPU generations are not cache coherent?

Tags: multithreading, caching, multicore, atomic, cpu-architecture

I'm designing a program and i found that assuming implicit cache coherency make the design much much easier. For example my single writer (always the same thread) multiple reader (always other threads) scenarios are not using any mutexes.

It's not a problem for current Intel CPU's. But i want this program to generate income for at least the next ten years (a short time for software) so i wonder if you think this could be a problem for future cpu architectures.

Comment: What happens when whatever your writer wants to update can't be done atomically?

Comment: In this case i use mutex operations or i send the worker thread into a signal handler, update and let it continue (yes i know this is dirty but improves performance a lot).

Comment: Cache coherency is not sufficient to get rid of locking. Compilers and CPUs reorder instructions in ways that can break multi-threaded programs, see the example program at the start of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_barrier

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect that future CPU generations will still handle cache coherence for you.  Without this, most mainstream programming methodologies would fail.  I doubt any CPU architecture that will be used widely in the next ten years will invalidate the current programming model - it may extend it, but it's difficult to drop something so widely assumed.

That being said, programming with the assumption of implicit cache coherency is not always a good idea.  There are many issues with [false sharing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_sharing) that can easily be avoided if you purposefully try to isolate your data.  Handling this properly can lead to huge performance boosts (rather, a lack of huge performance losses) on current generation CPUs.  Granted, it's more work in the design, but it is often required.

Answer (score 4):

We are already there. Computers claim cache coherency but at the same time they have a temporary store buffer for writes, reads can be completed via this buffer instead of the cache (ie the store buffer has just become a incoherent cache) and invalidate requests are also queued allowing the processor to temporarily use cache lines it knows are stale.

X86 doesn't use many of these techniques, but it does use some. As long as memory stays significantly slower than the CPU, expect to see more of these techniques and others yet devised to be used. Even itanium, failed as it is, uses many of these ideas, so expect intel to migrate them into x86 over time.

As for avoiding locks, etc:  it is always hard to guage people's level of expertise over the Internet so either you are misguided with what you think might work, or you are on the cutting edge of lockfree programming. Hard to tell.

Do you understand the MESI protocol, memory barriers and visibility?  Have you read stuff from Paul McKenney, etc?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know per se. But I'd like to see a trend toward non-cache coherent modes.

The conceptual mind shift is significant (can't just pass data in a method call, must pass it through a queue to an async method), but it's required as we move more and more into a multicore world anyway. The closer we get to one processor per memory bank the better. Because then we're working in a world of network message routing, where data is just not available rather than having threads that can silently stomp on data.

However, as Reed Copsey points out, the whole x86 world of computing is built on the assumption of cache coherency (which is even bigger than Microsoft's market share!). So it won't go away any time soon!

Comment: What's really necessary for scalability IMHO is a hybrid approach, with e.g. four groups of eight cores, where the cores in each group enforce consistency but the groups themselves do not.  At most eight of the cores would be able to cooperate on a single sub-task, but in most CPU-intensive tasks could be divided into enough different sub-tasks to keep all groups busy.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a paper from reputed authors in computer architecture area which argues that **cache coherence is here to stay**.

http://acg.cis.upenn.edu/papers/cacm12_why_coherence.pdf

"Why On-Chip Cache Coherence Is Here to Stay" -By Martin, Hill and Sorin

Answer (score 0):

You are making a strange request. You are asking for *our* (the SO community) *assumptions* about future CPU architectures - a very dangerous proposition. Are you willing to put your money where *our* mouth is? Because if we're wrong and your application will fail it will be you who's not making any money..

Anyway, I would suspect things are not going to change that dramatically because of all the legacy code that was written for single threaded execution but that's just my opinion.

Comment: Maybe somebody who is closer to the research labs and papers of Intel, ARM or SPARC then me knows something about it which i haven't seen. If there is currently nobody working on it it will never be ready for mainstream in only 10 years.

Answer (score 0):

The question seems misleading to me. The CPU architecture is not that important, what is important is the memory model of the platform you are working for.

You are developing the application is some environment, with some defined memory model. E.g. if you are currently targeting x86, you can be pretty sure any future platform will implement the same memory model when it is running x86 code. The same is true for Java or .NET VMs and other execution platforms.

If you expect to port your current application at some other platforms, if the platform memory model will be different, you will have to adjust for it, but in such case you are the one doing the port and you have the complete control over how you do it. This is however true even for current platforms, e.g. PowerPC memory model allows much more reorderings to happen than the x86 one.