# Is memory barrier or atomic operation required in a busy-wait loop?

Tags: c++, multithreading, gcc, memory-barriers, spinlock

Consider the following `spin_lock()` implementation, originally from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32658335/3169754):

```
void spin_lock(volatile bool* lock)  {  
    for (;;) {
        // inserts an acquire memory barrier and a compiler barrier
        if (!__atomic_test_and_set(lock, __ATOMIC_ACQUIRE))
            return;

        while (*lock)  // no barriers; is it OK?
            cpu_relax();
    }
}
```

What I already know:

- `volatile` prevents compiler from optimizing out `*lock` re-read on each iteration of the `while` loop;
- `volatile` [inserts neither memory nor compiler barriers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26307071/does-the-c-volatile-keyword-introduce-a-memory-fence);
- such an implementation actually works in GCC for `x86` (e.g. in Linux kernel) and some other architectures;
- at least one memory and compiler barrier [is required](https://jfdube.wordpress.com/2012/03/08/understanding-memory-ordering/) in `spin_lock()` implementation for a generic architecture; this example inserts them in [`__atomic_test_and_set()`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/_005f_005fatomic-Builtins.html).

**Questions:**

1. Is `volatile` enough here or are there any architectures or compilers where memory or compiler barrier or atomic operation is required in the `while` loop?

   1.1 According to `C++` standards?

   1.2 In practice, for known architectures and compilers, specifically for GCC and platforms it supports?
2. Is this implementation *safe* on all architectures supported by GCC and Linux? (It is at least *inefficient* on some architectures, right?)
3. Is the `while` loop safe according to `C++11` and its memory model?

---

There are several related questions, but I was unable to construct an explicit and unambiguous answer from them:

- [Q: Memory barrier in a single thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23078266/memory-barrier-in-a-single-thread)

  > In principle: Yes, if program execution moves from one core to the next, it might not see all writes that occurred on the previous core.
- [Q: memory barrier and cache flush](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11282899/memory-barrier-and-cache-flush)

  > On pretty much all modern architectures, caches (like the L1 and L2 caches) are ensured coherent by hardware. There is no need to flush any cache to make memory visible to other CPUs.
- [Q: Is my spin lock implementation correct and optimal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1383363/is-my-spin-lock-implementation-correct-and-optimal)
- [Q: Do spin locks always require a memory barrier? Is spinning on a memory barrier expensive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6810733/do-spin-locks-always-require-a-memory-barrier-is-spinning-on-a-memory-barrier-e)
- [Q: Do you expect that future CPU generations are not cache coherent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2151730/do-you-expect-that-future-cpu-generations-are-not-cache-coherent)

Comment: The first assumption is incorrect - on a multi CPU system, a `volatile` read is not guaranteed to synchronize caches. It is supposed to be used for device interfacing, not for threading.  See [Volatile and multithreading: is the following thread safe?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6592287/volatile-and-multithreading-is-the-following-thread-safe/6592371#6592371)

Comment: @BoPersson I believe he just means that it forces the compiler not to hoist the memory load operation out of the loop, so that it will at least re-read the local processor's cache. The question is about whether there actually exists an architecture for which cache coherency would actually be a real issue without a memory barrier, which implies that OP does understand that `volatile` does not create such a barrier.

Comment: @davmac, yes! This is exactly what I'm asking about.

Comment: @g-v btw "doesn't insert neither" is a double negative. You meant "inserts neither".

Comment: @davmac, thanks, fixed.

Comment: As a partial answer to your 1.2, here is how LLVM implements volatile and atomic memory orderings: http://llvm.org/docs/Atomics.html. So it's not safe there.

Comment: @Lorehead, thanks. LLVM states this for non-atomics (including volatile): "If there is a race on a given memory location, loads from that location return undef." Could you please clarify: does GCC expliticly promises stronger guaranties somewhere and is there an actual difference in operations generated for volatile loads by GCC and LLVM? BTW, In Microsoft's compiler volatile loads are explicitly promised to be atomic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7007403/are-volatile-reads-and-writes-atomic-on-windowsvisualc

Comment: @g-v The relevant section of the gcc manual: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Volatiles.html Note that g++ does *not* make the same guarantees for volatile references as for volatile pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. Is volatile enough here or are there any architectures or compilers where memory or compiler barrier or atomic operation is required in the while loop?

will the volatile code see the change.  Yes, but not necessarily as quickly as if there was a memory barrier.  At some point, some form of synchronization will occur, and the new state will be read from the variable, but there are no guarantees on how much has happened elsewhere in the code.

> 1.1 According to C++ standards?

From [cppreference : memory_order](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/memory_order)

It is the memory model and memory order which defines the generalized hardware that the code needs to work on.  For a message to pass between threads of execution, an inter-thread-happens-before relationship needs to occur.  This requires either...

- A synchronizes-with B
- A has a std::atomic operation before B
- A indirectly synchronizes with B (through X).
- A is sequenced before X which inter-thread happens before B
- A interthread happens before X and X interthread happens before B.

As you are not performing any of those cases there will be forms of your program where on some current hardware, it may fail.

In practice, the end of a time-slice will cause the memory to become coherent, or any form of barrier on the non-spinlock thread will ensure that the caches are flushed.

Not sure on the causes of the volatile read getting the "current value".

> 1.2 In practice, for known architectures and compilers, specifically for GCC and platforms it supports?

As the code is not consistent with the generalized CPU, from `C++11` then it is likely this code will fail to perform with versions of C++ which try to adhere to the standard.

From [cppreference : const volatile qualifiers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cv)
Volatile access stops optimizations from moving work from before it to after it, and from after it to before it.

> "This makes volatile objects suitable for communication with a signal handler, but not with another thread of execution"

So an implementation has to ensure that instructions are read from the memory location rather than any local copy.  But it does not have to ensure that the volatile write is flushed through the caches to produce a coherent view across all the CPUs.  In this sense, there is no time boundary on how long after a write into a volatile variable will become visible to another thread.

Also see [kernel.org why volatile is nearly always wrong in kernel](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.11/process/volatile-considered-harmful.html)

> Is this implementation safe on all architectures supported by GCC and Linux? (It is at least inefficient on some architectures, right?)

There is no guarantee the volatile message gets out of the thread which sets it.  So not really safe.  On linux it may be safe.

> Is the while loop safe according to C++11 and its memory model?

No - as it doesn't create any of the inter-thread messaging primitives.

Comment: Thanks! A very clear answer. Could you please clarify this point? `As the code is not consistent with the generalized CPU, from C++11 then it is likely this code will fail to perform with versions of C++ which try to adhere to the standard.` Do you have an example in mind what exactly may happen?

Answer (score 13):

This important: in C++ `volatile` has **nothing** at all to do with concurrency! The purpose of `volatile` is to tell the *compiler* that it shall not optimize accesses to the affected object. It does **not** tell the CPU anything, primarily because the CPU would know already whether memory would be `volatile` or not. The purpose of `volatile` is effectively to deal with memory mapped I/O.

The C++ standard is very clear in section 1.10 [intro.multithread] that unsynchronized access to an object which is modified in one thread and is accessed (modified or read) in another thread is undefined behavior. The synchronization primitives avoiding undefined behavior are library components like the atomic classes or mutexes. This clause mentions `volatile` only in the context of signals (i.e., as `volatile sigatomic_t`) and in the context of forward progress (i.e., that a thread will eventually do something which has an observable effect like accessing a `volatile` object or doing I/O). There is no mention of `volatile` in conjunction with synchronization.

Thus, unsynchronized assess to a variable shared across threads leads to undefined behavior. Whether it is declared `volatile` or not doesn't matter to this undefined behavior.

Comment: Thanks. So the answer for question ```3.``` is definitely *no*, it is not safe according to C++ standard.

Comment: That said, the GCC manual says that dereferencing a `volatile*` will actually reload the value from memory, and not be optimized away, so on GCC, the OP was correct about what it means.

Comment: @Lorehead: nope, that conclusion is false: the *compiler* will cause the data to be loaded but whether that affects what the CPU does in the context of a multi-core system is entirely unrelated. Some CPUs will actually reread the data (e.g., current x86 systems) while others will not.

Comment: I don't think we disagree at all, Dietmar.  The OP realized `volatile` doesn't guarantee cache coherency.

Answer (score 5):

From the [Wikipedia page on memory barriers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_barrier):

> ... Other architectures, such as the Itanium, provide separate "acquire" and "release" memory barriers which address the visibility of read-after-write operations from the point of view of a reader (sink) or writer (source) respectively.

To me this implies that Itanium requires a suitable fence to make reads/writes visible to other processors, but this may in fact just be for purposes of ordering. The question, I think, really boils down to:

**Does there exist an architecture where a processor might never update its local cache if not instructed to do so?** I don't know the answer, but if you posed the question in this form then someone else might. In such an architecture your code potentially goes into an infinite loop where the read of `*lock` always sees the same value.

In terms of general C++ legality, the one atomic test and set in your example isn't enough, since it implements only a single fence which will allow you to see the initial state of the `*lock` when entering the while loop but not to see when it changes (which results in undefined behavior, since you are reading a variable that is changed in another thread without synchronisation) - so the answer to your question (1.1/3) is *no*.

On the other hand, in practice, the answer to (1.2/2) is yes (given [GCC's volatile semantics](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Volatiles.html)), so long as the architecture guarantees cache coherence without explicit memory fences, which is true of x86 and probably for many architectures but I can't give a definite answer on whether it is true for all architectures that GCC supports. It is however generally unwise to knowingly rely on particular behavior of code that is technically undefined behavior according to the language spec, especially if it is possible to get the same result without doing so.

Incidentally, given that `memory_order_relaxed` exists, there seems little reason not to use it in this case rather than try to hand-optimise by using non-atomic reads, i.e. changing the while loop in your example to:

```
    while (atomic_load_explicit(lock, memory_order_relaxed)) {
        cpu_relax();
    }
```

On x86_64 for instance the atomic load becomes a regular `mov` instruction and the optimised assembly output is essentially the same as it would be for your original example.

Comment: "To me this implies that Itanium requires a suitable fence to make reads/writes visible to other processors." -- Is it really true that on Itanium (or some other architectures) changes may be not visible without a barrier? I though barriers only restrict *order* of such changes, but not affect visibility.

Comment: "it depends on what cpu_relax does" -- Lets assume that is does nothing or nothing related to barriers/cache flushes/etc. "is this from the Linux kernel btw?" -- No, it's just an example. Kernel version is here: http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/x86/include/asm/spinlock.h#L106

Comment: @g-v if `cpu_relax` does nothing relating to memory barriers then the answer to (3) is definitely "no" and I'm pretty sure the answer to (2) is also "no".

Comment: @g-v "Is it really true that on Itanium (or some other architectures) changes may be not visible without a barrier?" - it's certainly possible although I'm not knowledgable enough about other architectures to give you a definite answer. In any case correct ordering is critical to the operation of any type of mutex including a spinlock; you don't want to see a processor mutating the protected structure _after_ it has released the lock, right?

Comment: @g-v (although I suppose this isn't actually an issue with your example, since there is always a barrier when the spinlock is actually acquired. Hmmm).

Comment: "although I suppose this isn't actually an issue with your example..." - Yes! Also, it seems that IA64 implements cache coherency for data cache, but not for instruction cache: see http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=29961&seqNum=6 and http://www.puppetmastertrading.com/images/hwViewForSwHackers.pdf So my example probably is safe on Itanium.

Comment: "The question, I think, really boils down to: Does there exist an architecture where a processor might never update its local cache if not instructed to do so?" -- Yes, thanks. And also "Is there a compiler where ```volatile``` will not work in such scenario?" and "Does this non-standard ```volatile``` behaviour always work in GCC?".

Comment: Because `volatile` is generally accepted to mean that the address might refer to a location whose value is controlled by hardware (i.e. that is memory-mapped IO address), I think you can be fairly sure that GCC and other compilers will do what you want here. But see amended answer - there's no real need to rely on this when you can use an atomic load with `memory_order_relaxed` anyway.

Comment: Great hint! Is seems that if we'll use ```memory_order_consume``` instead of ```memory_order_relaxed``` here, it will be safe even on architectures without cache coherency (if ```spin_unlock()``` uses ```memory_order_release``` barrier). See "Release-Consume ordering" here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/memory_order It also states: "On all mainstream CPUs other than DEC Alpha, dependency ordering is automatic, no additional CPU instructions are issued for this synchronization mode, only certain compiler optimizations are affected"

Comment: @g-v I am fairly certain that any atomic operation has to be safe without cache coherency anyway. The memory ordering constraints are for surrounding reads/writes to non-atomics. Long discussion here, though it's for C++ I think the same principle applies to C: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30691135/basic-spin-lock-mutex-implementation-ordering/30692887#30692887

Comment: Ah, I see now. I also found this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27333311/will-two-relaxed-writes-to-the-same-location-in-different-threads-always-be-seen

Comment: @davmac As for what GCC does and does not guarantee, here is the relevant section of the manual: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Volatiles.html

Comment: @Lorehead thanks, I've added this link to the answer.